# Entity Framework authorization IDbCommandTreeInterceptor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I’m trying to implement a general way to add an authorization SQL filter to all our Entity Framework queries.
For this I’m using IDbCommandTreeInterceptor and a DefaultExpressionVisitor.
The models is basic: all our entities have a RegionID, and we have in a Db context a DynRegions entity set containing all the regions users have access to.

So what I would like is to add dynamically the Any filter in the linq query below (which produces a SQL SELECT EXISTS):

```
var query = context.Contacts
 .Where(
    c =>
        context.DynRegions.Any(r => r.UserId == "150293818FC844F89AB36D044988F146" && r.RegionId == c.RegionId) &&
        c.LastName.StartsWith("A"));
```

I've started with this code:

```
public class RegionsInterceptor : IDbCommandTreeInterceptor
{
    public void TreeCreated(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
    {
        if (interceptionContext.OriginalResult.DataSpace != DataSpace.SSpace) return;

        var queryCommand = interceptionContext.Result as DbQueryCommandTree;
        if (queryCommand == null) return;

        var dbContext = interceptionContext.DbContexts.FirstOrDefault() as CrmContext;
        if (dbContext == null) return;

        var newQuery = queryCommand.Query.Accept(new RegionsQueryVisitor(dbContext));
        interceptionContext.Result = new DbQueryCommandTree(
                                            queryCommand.MetadataWorkspace,
                                            queryCommand.DataSpace,
                                            newQuery);
    }
}

public class RegionsQueryVisitor : DefaultExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly CrmContext dbContext;

    public RegionsQueryVisitor(CrmContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public override DbExpression Visit(DbScanExpression expression)
    {
        var dbExpression = base.Visit(expression);

        var currentExpressionBinding = DbExpressionBuilder.Bind(dbExpression);
        var currentEntityRegionId = DbExpressionBuilder.Property(currentExpressionBinding.Variable, "RegionId");

        var rolesExpression = expression.Target.EntityContainer.GetEntitySetByName("DynRole", true).Scan();
        var rolesExpressionBinding = rolesExpression.Bind();

        var rolesRegionIdProperty = DbExpressionBuilder.Property(rolesExpressionBinding.Variable, "RegionId");
        var rolesUserIdProperty = DbExpressionBuilder.Property(rolesExpressionBinding.Variable, "UserId");
        var userIdParameter = DbExpressionBuilder.Constant("150293818FC844F89AB36D044988F146");

        var anyRolesExpression =
            rolesExpression.Any(p => 
                    DbExpressionBuilder.Equal(rolesUserIdProperty, userIdParameter)
                        .And(
                    DbExpressionBuilder.Equal(rolesRegionIdProperty, currentEntityRegionId)));


        var binding = expression.Bind();

        return binding.Filter(anyRolesExpression);
    }    
}
```

I'm getting an error: The referenced variable 'Var_2' is not defined in the current scope.
The error occurs on the following line:

```
interceptionContext.Result = new DbQueryCommandTree(
                                             queryCommand.MetadataWorkspace,
                                             queryCommand.DataSpace,
                                             newQuery);
```

Any idea? Has anyone already written such interceptor/visitor?
Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Seems to be too overcomplicated. How about wrapping context query creation with adding security condition?

Comment: Hi, I looked at the article, where do you exactly struggle?  You can take that as a basis, replace IsDeletedColumnName to RegionColumnName, bool to int and work from there. You will have to implement passing RegionID into visitor, thought.

Comment: Hi Vitaliy, can you please clarify? Where would you wrap context query creation? Thks

Comment: Don't use context.Contacts e.t.c. directly. Instead user helper routine to create generic DBSet of proper type append where condition and return it as queryable.